# Unpublishing and publishing the android app

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I have an android app with some id as `com.project.idea` and it was already in the play store with status as published from old developer account.

But i want to move this app to another developer account so i have done below steps

1. Unpublished the current active app with id `com.project.idea` from the playstore from old developer account
2. Created another developer account and trying to upload the same app/apk file with id `com.project.idea` as before, but during uploading it was telling me

   Upload failed

   You need to use a different package name because "com.project.idea" already exists in Google Play.

Actually i have unpublished the old app already from old developer account and why it was still not accepting the same apk file from new developer account? so does this means even though we unpublished the app with one id, we can't upload the same apk with same id from other developer account ? and need to change the app id for sure ?

or it takes some time to reflect the changes of unpublished app on play store ?

(`Actually i am new to this process`) Can some one take me through this ?

Comment: Yeah. You need to change app package name before publish it

Comment: thanks, does app id changing involves a change at a lot of places(i mean package name etc.,) or else just in manifest file ?

Comment: You need to modify in manifest file and updates also in a sub package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot transfer apps between accounts like this. Google needs to transfer the app for you but there are a number of steps you need to take first to make sure the app can be transferred.

Please refer to this [Google page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en) for further instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think with transfer option you can take old package id.